# Formation of Calcite from Calcium carbonate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

So, in lab we are forming the different polymorphs of calcium carbonate. It required us to age the sample that was prepared for the formation of calcite for one week. This sample mixture was suspended in water. Whilst the other samples that were prepared for vaterite and aragonite were immediately washed/filtered.

Why do you need to age a calcite sample for a week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that the production of the calcite takes a decent amount of time as there are 2 stages being undertaken for the crystallization of the amorphous calcium carbonate (ACC). The first of these is relatively fast whilst the second stage is the one that you want to be looking at as it is roughly 10 times slower. This is the stage which looks at a dissolution and precipitation mechanism.